# D3 - How to use conditional statements in enter

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-first-v-last-arrows-xzwlwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts)

I have a bar chart where the bars are created with start and finish values.

The start and finish values can be higher or lower than each other so I want to show arrows on the bars showing if the values are going up or down.

This works in my example but breaks when the values and very close. In my example the first bar - start: 100, finish: 100.1 but the arrows shows down.

I'm not sure why this is happening but in these cases I wanted to hide the arrow.

How do I add a conditional statement to this part of the enter phase, something like.

```
if(d.start !== d.finish){}
    bar.enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", d => this.x(d.phase) + this.x.bandwidth()/2)
        .attr("y1", d => this.y(d.start) + ((d.start < d.finish) ? -5 : 5) )
        .attr("x2", d => this.x(d.phase) + this.x.bandwidth()/2)
        .attr("y2", d => this.y(d.finish) + ((d.start < d.finish) ? 5 : -5) )
        .attr("stroke","#000")
        .attr("stroke-width",2)
        .attr("marker-end","url(#arrow)");    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a conditional in your 'marker-end' and, if you didn't want the line either, 'stroke-width' attributes, i.e. for some defined 'smallAmount':

```
bar.enter()
  .append("line")
    .attr("x1", d => this.x(d.phase) + this.x.bandwidth()/2)
    .attr("y1", d => this.y(d.start) + ((d.start < d.finish) ? -5 : 5) )
    .attr("x2", d => this.x(d.phase) + this.x.bandwidth()/2)
    .attr("y2", d => this.y(d.finish) + ((d.start < d.finish) ? 5 : -5) )
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.abs(d.finish - d.start) < smallAmount ?  0 : 2)
    .attr("marker-end", d => Math.abs(d.finish - d.start) < smallAmount ? "none" : "url(#arrow)");
```